# Getting rid of "count" column by replicating rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which looks like this

```
string count values
----
string1 3 vals1
string2 2 vals2
```

And I want to get rid of the "count" column by repeating each row "count" times to get a DataFrame like this

```
string1 vals1
string1 vals1
string1 vals1
string2 vals2
string2 vals2
```

Is there an easy Pandas recipe for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there's a better native way, but you could do something like

```
>>> df.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), df["count"])]
    string  count values
0  string1      3  vals1
0  string1      3  vals1
0  string1      3  vals1
1  string2      2  vals2
1  string2      2  vals2
```

to get something to start from, and then delete count and (if you wanted) `reset_index(drop=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any easy way to do this (as in a function).  Here is a workaround that creates a nested list which is then used to recreate the extended dataframe.

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'string': ['string1', 'string2'], 'count': [3, 2], 'values': ['vals1', 'vals2']})
>>> df
   count   string values
0      3  string1  vals1
1      2  string2  vals2

# Use nested list comprehension to repeat selected columns of each row `count` times.
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[row['string'], row['values']]
                     for _, row in df.iterrows() 
                     for _ in range(row['count'])],
                   columns=['string', 'values'])

>>> df2
    string values
0  string1  vals1
1  string1  vals1
2  string1  vals1
3  string2  vals2
4  string2  vals2
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

df.groupby(['string','values']).apply(lambda x:   pd.concat([x]*sum(x['count']))).reset_index(drop=True)

assuming you want the sum in cases of more than one count line.